# Printing PDF lables to a Zebra printer (420d)

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

In my webshop, I'm able to download a delivery slip as a pdf file. I have built a .NET service that uses `FileSystemWatcher` that monitors my "Print" folder. The service will process all `.pdf` and `.zpl` files inside the folder.

All `.zpl` files will be opened and written to a Zebra 420d printer directly using the Windows drivers using the `RawPrinterHelper` class. It works as expected!

My issue is the `.pdf` files. When I print the files manually from a browser in Windows 10 to the Zebra 420d printer, it works perfectly fine. But when I try to print them from my service, the size of the label will be very small. It looks like the content has shrunk.

```
public static bool PrintPdf(string filepath, string printerName)
{
    try
    {
        var doc = new PdfDocument();
        doc.LoadFromFile(filepath);
        doc.PrinterName = printerName;
        doc.PrintDocument.Print();
        doc.Dispose();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // More code ...
    }
}
```

I have googled all night and tried various ways to convert a PDF to PNG/SVG to ZPL, but non worked.

How can I print labels in PDF-format to a Zebra 420d printer using c#?

Edit: I tried also to convert the PDF to a BMP and then to GRF (Zebras native language). Still not working. All I get is a blank page.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, not many that knows what ZPL is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

I didn't need any conversion at all. I had only to reinstall and adjust the printer driver settings and modify my code to work with the new settings.

This is my final code:

```
 public static bool Print(string filepath, string printerName)
    {
        try
        {
            var doc = new PdfDocument();
            doc.LoadFromFile(filepath);
            doc.PrinterName = printerName;

            var psize = new PaperSize("Custom Paper Size", 417, 1007);
            doc.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
            doc.PageSettings.Rotate = PdfPageRotateAngle.RotateAngle180;

            doc.PrintDocument.Print();
            doc.Dispose();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // More code ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you indeed elaborate some more about the libraries you are using?

Comment: Is this UWP only? I can't find the PdfDocument class for WPF.

Comment: Looks like [Syncfusion Essential PDF](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/getting-started) is used. Another PDF vendor also has the same APIs, but that is a pirated version of Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

Download Spire.Pdf package from nuget package downloader to access PdfDocument class